# How to hide node.js warning when running Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack-dev-server

When I build my image, and run, I kept getting this message

❌❌❌

> (node:26) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE]
> DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated.
> Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:26) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE]
> DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated.
> Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option. Starting the development
> server...

```
➜  ace git:(main) ✗ docker build -t ace-image .      
[+] Building 9.7s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 625B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                     0.5s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:b4a72f83f52bbe3970bb74a15e44ec4cf6e873ad4787473dfc8a26f5b4e29  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring context: 24.22kB                                                                                  0.1s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] RUN npm install --quiet                                                                              0.0s
 => [5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                                           8.9s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                               0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:478016d17cf8826bbbb94faecc2a4f556a5f77280c41342bd27b1b200f2870ba                          0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/ace-image                                                                          0.0s 
➜  ace git:(main) ✗ docker run -p 3000:3000 ace-image

> ace@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start --quiet

(node:26) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:26) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
Starting the development server...

Compiled successfully!

You can now view ace in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.2:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
Compiling...
Compiled successfully!
webpack compiled successfully
```

As you can see, I've tried to silent it already, but not working

I tried `CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--quiet"]`

```
# Set the base image to Node 16
FROM node:16-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies quietly
RUN npm install --quiet

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Run the command to start the server
CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--quiet"]
```

Comment: You'd hide it, by not running the webpack dev server. As the output says, `create a production build, use npm run build`. Then, you'd copy that into a web server like nginx to run it. You don't need Nodejs to run bundled code

Comment: I don't get you. npm start is the last command in Dockerfile. Can you help me share the Dockerfile that you think is right so I can learn from you ?

Comment: You'd add more lines with `FROM nginx` and `COPY`. As mentioned, node isn't needed anymore after `npm run build` therefore, if you don't want to see that warning, `npm start` or `react-scripts start` shouldn't be used

Comment: @code-8 can you post package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Use [--no-deprecation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/cli.html#--no-deprecation):

```bash
# Dockerfile
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```json
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --no-deprecation [entrypoint e.g. index.js]",
...
```

You may want to add a new script such as `start:production` with this flag so you can still see the warnings during development.

Answer (score 0):

After building your app with `npm run build` you no longer need to use the `start` command to launch the development server. You can instead define a multi-stage Docker build to serve your app with nginx.

A `Dockerfile` like this should help:

```
# Stage 1: Compile and build the app

# Set the build stage image to Node 16
FROM node:16-alpine as build

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies quietly
RUN npm install --quiet

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build


# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx

# Set the base running image to nginx Alpine
FROM nginx:alpine-perl

# Copy the output from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

You need to change /app/dist/**my-app** to the name of your app.

As you can see in the `Dockerfile`, no custom `CMD` command is defined. The nginx image will serve the contents of `/usr/share/nginx/html` by default.